# Luatex last version

Tags: luatex

I use lualatex for compiling my docs (Windows with TeXLiVe 2021, up to date), and the version of my lualatex/luatex/luahbtex executables are 1.13.2.
I saw that the "current" version of luatex is - since 2021-12-31 - LuaTeX 1.15.0.
https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/NEWS?view=markup

I wonder why my version of luatex is not "up to date"... and how eventually update ?

Tks-

Comment: texlive will only provide new executables with texlive 2022.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437